# How do I block all the keyboard shortcuts in linux

Tags: linux

How do I block all the keyboard shortcuts in linux? Can these shortcuts be generated from some script? If yes, how can I trap these events so that system does not process those key events.

I read about XGrabKeyboard for trapping all key events but not sure this will work for touch screens as well.

Comment: You really hate your users, don't you?

Comment: Why do you want to block shortcuts ? If you are trying to avoid reboots with ctrl+alt+del, there is better solutions.

Comment: Try issuing the `halt` command. Although it might have other side effects, you don't seem to be concerned about that.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to block ctrl+alt+del, just edit /etc/inittab and comment this line:

```
ca:12345:ctrlaltdel:/sbin/shutdown -t1 -a -r now
```

Comment: This is required for an embedded device where there won't be any keyboard and it is a touch based device. The key events, if generated by an untrusted application or through scripts should be trapped before it reaches the system for action.